# Fit textfield width when column is resized

Tags: dynamic, javafx, width, javafx-8

I have a treeTableView and in its header I have a Label and Textbox. I want the width of textbox to increase also when the column is increased by resizing of it.

How to do that?

How to get dynamic column width? Or how to set dynamic width to textbox as per column?

Code:

```
<TableView fx:id="tableView" layoutX="1.0" layoutY="1.0"
           minHeight="580.0" prefWidth="434.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"
           AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"
           AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn style="-fx-font-family: Calibri; -fx-font-size: 11px;" text="MessageId">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="messageId" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>

        <TableColumn prefWidth="110.0" style="-fx-font-family: Calibri; -fx-font-size: 11px;" text="Digest Reference">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="digestReference" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>

        <TableColumn prefWidth="115.0" style="-fx-font-family: Calibri; -fx-font-size: 11px;" text="Message Reference">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="messageRef" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>

        <TableColumn prefWidth="115.0" style="-fx-font-family: Calibri; -fx-font-size: 11px;" text="Deal Number">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="dealNo" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>

        <TableColumn style="-fx-font-family: Calibri; -fx-font-size: 11px;" text="Digest Value">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="digestValue" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>

        <TableColumn prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-font-family: Calibri; -fx-font-size: 11px;" text="Updated Date Time">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="updateTime" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>

    </columns>

    <columnResizePolicy>
        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
    </columnResizePolicy>
</TableView>
```

JAVA Code:

```
for (TableColumn<NonRepudiation, ?> tableColumn : tableView.getColumns()) {

double width = tableColumn.getWidth();

VBox vBox = new VBox();
vBox.autosize();
vBox.setPrefWidth(tableColumn.getMaxWidth());

double width = tableColumn.getWidth();

VBox vBox = new VBox();
vBox.autosize();
vBox.setPrefWidth(tableColumn.getMaxWidth());

HBox lableBox = new HBox();
lableBox.setPrefWidth(width);
lableBox.getStyleClass().add("labelBoxTxt");

StackPane HL    =   new StackPane();
HL.getStyleClass().add("greyBorder");

Label label = new Label(tableColumn.getText());
label.setPrefWidth(width);
label.alignmentProperty().setValue(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.setPrefWidth(width);
textField.textProperty().addListener(filterTable(tableColumn));

HBox textInputBox = new HBox();
textInputBox.getChildren().add(textField);
lableBox.getChildren().add(label);

HBox.setMargin(textField, new Insets(3,3,3,0));

vBox.getChildren().addAll(lableBox, HL, textInputBox);

tableColumn.setGraphic(vBox);
}
```

Comment: Hm, How to do what? Column width of what? A Screenshot and a bit code would help to find a solution.

Comment: There is no label and textbox in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Set a css class to your talbe view.

```
<TableView styleClass="k-table-view"
```

Then add css class to vbox

```
vBox.getStyleClass().add("k-column-graphic");
```

Add css rule

```
    .k-table-view .column-header > .label  {
    -fx-content-display: graphic-only;
}

.k-column-graphic {
    -fx-alignment: center-left;
}
```

I am having dynamic width for the graphic.

Comment: Is it applicable to your previous question in the comment -> "I have this code -- tableView.setTableMenuButtonVisible(true); --. If I make that text as null or empty then header text is not showing in dropdown. Only checkbox is appearing." ? Since you are showing graphic only.

Comment: After I write this css rule. I am able to achieve what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to use `HBox.setHgrow()` method. Here refactored code of yours:

```
for ( TableColumn tableColumn : tableView.getColumns() ) {

    // build label
    Label label = new Label( tableColumn.getText() );
    HBox lableBox = new HBox( label );
    lableBox.getStyleClass().add( "labelBoxTxt" );
    lableBox.setAlignment( Pos.CENTER );

    // build hor line
    StackPane HL = new StackPane();
    HL.getStyleClass().add( "greyBorder" );

    // build text field
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    HBox.setHgrow( textField, Priority.ALWAYS );
    HBox.setMargin( textField, new Insets( 3 ) );
    HBox textInputBox = new HBox( textField );

    // put together
    VBox vBox = new VBox( lableBox, HL, textInputBox );
    tableColumn.setText( "" );
    tableColumn.setGraphic( vBox );
}
```

Comment: thank you dude. It works as I expected. Long live. Regards.

Comment: Can we use something else other then -- tableColumn.setText( "" ); ?

Comment: I have this code -- tableView.setTableMenuButtonVisible(true); --. If I make that text as null or empty then header text is not showing in dropdown. Only checkbox is appearing.

Comment: @php83, hmm then you need to re-design the visuals of tablecolumn with including setText(). By default the text is shown on right while the graphic is on the left. If you want to align them vertically, you may need to access (by lookup) the Labeled node of tablecolumn, and set (maybe by overriding css selector) its contentDisplayProperty accordingly.

Comment: I have tried it but I am not able to made it. Could you please create some code or example how it should ne done. We have the code above.